# Updating Mysql records using multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am sending data using POST in the following fashion: 
data:

```
('acctNbr_1',3750613,21900.05,'Chico',2016,11,0,21900.05,2909.25),
('acctNbr_2',2123480,18512.42,'Chico',2016,11,0,18512.42,918.18),…
```

I am then using determining whether the record is already in the database.  If it isn't I am using the the following PHP to insert into mysql database as new record:

```
$data = mysqli_real_escape_string(dbase, $_POST["data"]);

$sql=("INSERT INTO printinputold (htmlid,accno,dollars,division,year,month,Is_Online,lastyearsales,actualnum)   VALUES ".$data."");

if ($dbase->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $dbase->error;
}
```

This works fine to save a new record.

But if the record exists I am not sure how to use the same $data to update an existing record.

Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated.
Thanks,
Jim

Comment: so an UPDATE query? what you are asking is not clear.

Comment: edited initial question to clarify

Comment: same answer from me, so use a update querry

Comment: yup got that it would be an update.  I don't know how to construct it and incorporate the $data variable